# Problem while installing spaCy on windows 10

Tags: python, python-venv, virtual-environment

I'm trying to install spaCy on my windows 10 machine, but I'm facing difficulties while activating the virtual environment.

These are the steps that I have followed:

```
python -m pip install -U pip                   # update pip
git clone https://github.com/explosion/spaCy   # clone spaCy
cd spaCy                                       # navigate into directory
python -m venv .env                            # create environment in .env 
source .env/bin/activate                       # activate virtual environment
```

But, after I try to activate the virtual environment using source `source .env/bin/activate`, it gives me this: `bash: .env/bin/activate: No such file or directory`

I'm using Python 3.7. What can be the possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

`source .env/Scripts/activate` got it working